# Strange query bug with Next js, Knex, and SWR

Tags: javascript, next.js, knex.js, swr

Using `Next` API routes and `Knex` + `MySQL`, and using `React` and `SWR` for fetching, I get a strange bug. If a request fails, my queries start appending `, *` to the `select` statement, resulting in SQL syntax errors. For example, the query should use `select *`, but comes out as `select *, *` and then `select *, *, *` and so on. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

SWR fetch:

```
export const swrFetcher = async (...args) => {
  const [url, contentType = 'application/json'] = args;
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': contentType,
    },
  });
  if (!res.ok) throw new Error(res.statusText);
  const json = await res.json();
  return json;
};

const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/user/me', swrFetcher, {
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
    revalidateOnReconnect: false,
    revalidateOnMount: true,
  });
```

knex query:

```
const User = knex(TABLE_NAMES.user);
export const readById = (id) => User.select('*').where({ id });
```

Comment: probably can't reuse the knex table this way. will try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to create the `knex` instance within the function call and not reuse the same every time, like it's currently happening.

```js
export const readById = (id) => {
    const User = knex(TABLE_NAMES.user);
    return User.select('*').where({ id });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I actually realized this after writing the question. Sometimes my brain is too foggy to think until I write out the problem lol.